# Standard practice for earth connection when we use transformers

Tags: transformer, grounding, three-phase

We bought the below device (two transformers inside a housing) from a local manufacturer and the connections was as noted in the schematic. We don't want to use the neutral from the utility. That's the reason why we thought of using a transformer to step down 415V to 230V.

Now we want to use the supplied transformer. We are getting 230V at the output side of the device. There is no confusion in that.

If we are connecting these two terminals, 230V terminal to line terminal of PC socket and 0V terminal to neutral terminal of PC socket, the PC will work.

1. What to connect to the earth pin in the PC socket
   Do we need connect earth pin to earth connection from the utility? Or we can discard the earth connection? Or do we need to short one of the line to earth
2. In order for the current to flow to earth connection if there is a fault (any one line touches the enclosure), will there be a current flow to the earth with this connection?(Current needs a closed path to flow back to the source.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fElcGu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNgrAS.png)</sup>

Which one of the above method is the correct one?

Please bear with me if this is a stupid question. But want to understand the standard practice.

Comment: What you describe cannot exist. You can however use a single phase transformer between two phases and have a single phase output or have a true three phase transformer and only load one of the phases. Please draw a schematic of what you have and how you connected things.

Comment: It would help if you said which exact 3-phase to 1-phase isolation transformer you bought. And devices that have a plug with earth connection must be connected to an earthed socket - if it is not otherwise obvious, it reads in the device manuals, and in practice the metal case of a device would float capacitively at 115VAC due to Y filter capacitors from PE to Live and Neutral inside the power supply.

Comment: The case of the PSU is connected to earth via the PSU. The PSU needs an earth connection for safety. It will need a circuit breaker of some sort between the transformer and the attached devices.

Comment: "*Now we connected earth and neutral (of power cord) to the terminal marked 0V.*" You need to undo this immediately. The earth wires need to be connected to the supply earth. It appears that you are way out of your depth on this and don't understand some basics. I think you need professional help.

Comment: Echoing @winny - there is no such thing as a three phase to single phase transformer. Details are needed i.e. data sheets or some other form of manufacturer's specification. Don't link to ebay et al.

Comment: Is this really a transformer? Or a converter/inverter?

Comment: What makes you think that is a three-phase transformer? It looks like a single-phase transformer with split primaries and secondaries. Can you post a sharp, cropped photo of the terminals and any labelling?

Comment: @Transistor I was wrong in mentioning the transformer type. It is two step down transformers in the same enclosure with connections between the two.  I cant take a photo of the terminals right now. Will post it later. The labels are the same mentioned in the schematic. R,Y,B where we connect phase wires(Phase to phase voltage is 415V) and at the other side there are terminals marked as in the schematic(230V,0V)

Comment: That's not a 3 phase transformer.

Comment: @Andy it does transform 3 phase delta to single phase if the ratios are correct , the voltage is also correct. but one output must be PE protected, usually the centre tap as done in NA or one side as done in EU [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: No @TonyStewartEE75 that isn't a three phase to single phase transformer. They don't exist.

Comment: It is and does work with 2 cores

Comment: Then it's a two phase to single phase transformer. I didn't downvote your answer BTW. I can prove it of course (like last time).

Comment: right (?) how do you explain they have the correct output voltage and this is a PE question https://tinyurl.com/yfo8rxss

Comment: Vector geometry 101

Comment: The question needs complete sentences, periods only at the ends of complete sentences and question marks at the ends of the questions.

Comment: How did this trivial question get misunderstood?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Hi, Please be careful that your comments don't look like they are harassing other users. Users don't have to reply to comments. Please don't add comments "pushing" for a reply. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I appreciate your moderation and I hope you appreciate my acuity in answering this question unlike some others

Answer (score 2):

> What happen if we didnt supply earth connections.[?] Will it cause any damage to the PC or is there any safety issue?

If the PC has an earth connection point. There may be a safety issue. It will not directly cause damage, but it may defeat protection measures built into the PC and thus make it more vulnerable to damage.

> We want to know what is the usual practice when we use a 3 phase to single phase isolation transformer to power PC kind of devices (which can affected by EMI).

Use of a 3-phase to single-phase transformer is not a usual practice. It is a method of reducing the imbalance among the phases resulting from single-phase loads that are not equally distributed. The illustrated 3-phase to single-phase connection is the least effective of several such schemes.

Protective earth ground connections (PE) need to be connected to earth by means of an electrode driven into the ground or some other metal structure that is partly buried.

Neutral can be connected to PE and may be required to be connected to PE, but PE should not be connected to earth by connecting to neutral.

Any outer metal case or exposed metal frame of a transformer should be connected to PE. However that connection should not serve as the PE connection for other equipment unless the PE electrode is located at the transformer.

Re added ELCB question: Refer to usage guidance for ELCB and relevant electrical safety code. That seems the appropriate sensing point for some types of ELCB. Whether or not ELCB is advisable or required depends on code and installation details.

Comment: Yes Protective Earth Ground and Neutral are tied because the general term “ground” is defined as 0V at that point.  It may be any logical tap on the secondary .

Answer (score 0):

PC power supplies use an RF line filter to bypass noise in both directions to earth ground.

It works, but not having an earth ground without a double-insulated user interface is a violation of safety for insulation breakdown to case from transient feedthru  in transformers.  (e.g. lightning noise on common mode voltage.)

How hard is it to connect a protective earth ground? for safety's sake. really . unless you never get lightning there ;)

- you must connect a PE bond to the secondary of HV transformer according to your local power safety standards

A 3 ph to 1 ph transformer is basically a \$\sqrt(3):1\$ ratio transformer for line-line or delta input connection.

I may have assumed the wrong Delta supply voltage but shown here is 1:1 transformers

This a PE safety question, not a question on how to generate 1 phase from 3.

[image]

Comment: Who DV'd this and on what basis?

Comment: On the basis there isnt any phase shift between the 3 input voltages

Comment: @MissMulan. can you not see the 120 deg phases in the plots below the output. How did you confirm your incorrect assumptions?  i chose phases of 0, 120, 240.  Pls advise/revise your assertion.

Comment: Clearly a lot of (-3) invalid critics …. input Phase AB+BC= Phase AC out times N ratio

Comment: rather AB-BC=AC

Comment: I will do a drive-by upvote.  If the three inputs are labelled R, Y and B, then it's a strong hint that it's a 3 phase supply.